# Question on using shared memory table of structs

Tags: pointers, struct

We have a large array of structs in shared memory that several programs attach to and
access.  Protections are made using semaphores to protect it.

The code has a function that takes a pointer to a new structure element the caller
wants to send to the participant user process.  in the helper function that does the
handoff, it copies the incoming new structure using the pointer to the structure data
to the table of structs as in:

foo[idx]->q[index] = *bar;

does this actually copy the data from the callers address space into the shared
memory or should the code be using memcpy using the bar pointer as the source
and the foo[idx]->q[index] as the target?

Comment: Without seeing more code it's hard to be sure what you're doing.  Is `foo` the pointer to shared memory, or is `foo[idx]->q`, or something else?  What are the types of the objects involved?  But the basic principle is that the `=` operator in C is **always** a shallow copy.  If you assign a pointer it only copies the pointer.  If you assign a struct, it copies all its members, but if some of those members are pointers then the data to which they point is not copied.

Comment: Foo is declared as an array of structs globally as in:

struct _foo_table_type {
   int counter;
   int another_counter;
  struct FOOTYPE q[MAXFOOS];
} IPC_FOO_TYPE;

the code that loads the foo table declares it globally:

FOO_TABLE_TYPE *foo;

then references is as an array:

foo[idx]->q[fooidx] = *newfoo;

this is what they are currently doing.  I am not sure that this actually fills out the array element q inside the foo table in shared memory.

Comment: Okay then yes, this really does copy an object of type `struct FOOTYPE`.  You could do `memcpy(&foo[idx]->q[index], bar, sizeof(struct FOOTYPE))` and it would have exactly the same effect.

Comment: this code is used as a message passing between 2 programs.  the mechanism is done using msgsnd and msgrcv calls.  the app front ends these lower level system calls with msg_snd and msg_rcv which use the foo array in shared memory to do the actual copying.  a small packet goes into the IPC message queue with the index into the array where it the msg_rcv can find the response.   the problem here is that the data is not being filled out in the structure.  I'll test this out further tomorrow.  thx.

Comment: Wait a minute, is there a mismatch between `FOO_TABLE_TYPE` and `struct _foo_table_type`?  Because if `foo` is a pointer to `struct _foo_table_type`, then `foo[idx]` is actually of type `struct _foo_table_type`, not a pointer, and so `foo[idx]->q` should not compile.

Comment: my mistake.  the are using the following:

foo->q[idx]   foo is a pointer to a foo_struct_type.  q inside is an array of foo_struct_types inside.

Comment: the issue was on the dequeueing side that was inadvertently dequeueing twice overlaying the 1st dequeue result.  the operation of assignment using the *bar does in fact fill out the entire struct of foo in the shared memory context.   thx. for your help Nate. :)